# Expectation of Brownian motion increment and exponent of it

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

While reading a proof of a theorem I stumbled upon the following derivation which I failed to replicate myself. Let $\mu$ be a constant and $B(t)$ be a standard Brownian motion with $t > s$. Show that

$$ E\left( (B(t)−B(s))e^{−\mu (B(t)−B(s))} \right)  = - \frac{d}{d\mu}(e^{\mu^2(t-s)/2})$$

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The increments $B(t)-B(s)$ have a Gaussian distribution with mean zero and variance $t-s$, for $t>s$. Hence
$$E\left( (B(t)−B(s))e^{−\mu (B(t)−B(s))} \right)   =\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-\mu x}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(t-s)}}\,dx$$
$$=-\mu(t-s)e^{\mu^2(t-s)/2}=- \frac{d}{d\mu}(e^{\mu^2(t-s)/2}).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $m:=\mu$ and $X:=B(t)-B(s)$, so that $X\sim N(0,t-s)$ and [hence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions) 
$Ee^{-mX}=e^{m^2(t-s)/2}$. So, in view of the [Leibniz_integral_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement), the expectation in question is
$$EXe^{-mX}=-E\frac d{dm}e^{-mX}=-\frac d{dm}Ee^{-mX}=-\frac d{dm}e^{m^2(t-s)/2},$$
by as desired.